# How can I read or write to json file in google storage bucket (not public access) using Go

Tags: json, go, bucket

I am trying to read/write a json file to google cloud storage bucket using Golang. I know how to write to the file system. This will not work if the json file is in the bucket.

Comment: I use google cloud not Amazon

Comment: Oops, start here: https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/storage

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google's go SDK for reading and writing files to Google storage bucket. You can find the golang sdk for storage here - [Golang SDK](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/storage?tab=doc)

- Example for reading a file - [here](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/storage?tab=doc#example-ObjectHandle.NewReader)
- Example for writing a file - [here](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/storage?tab=doc#example-ObjectHandle.NewWriter)

They confirm to io.Reader and io.Writer interfaces so, once you have handle you can work with them like normal file reader/writer.